# How do I count the features percentage when only the label is true in Python machine learning?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, count, jupyter

I'm using Jupyter to learn machine learning.

I would like to know how to count the features percentage (Style, Typo, Layout percentage) when only the "Like" column is 1?

[image]

Comment: Could you show what your output layer is? I believe to see percentages a sigmoid function would be necessary. And your labels are into too unique. I would think that you would need 3 diffrent networks to predict 3 diffrent labels to form the combined form. I.e. NN1 = Style, NN2 = Typo, NN3 = layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to find the percentage of each unique value for each column when Like == 1. If that's the case, you can do:

```
df[df['Like'] == 1]['Style'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100

df[df['Like'] == 1]['Typo'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100

df[df['Like'] == 1]['Layout'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
```